# Is it possible to put two function in a one setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know about setInterval syntax:

> setInterval(function,milliseconds)

I want two functions to be called at the same time instead of one for every 8 seconds. Is there any way to do it by setInterval function like this?

> setInterval(function1, function2, 8000)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, write a `wrapper function` for that both functions.

Try

```
setInterval(function(){ function1(); function2(); },8000)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not a "Yes", it's a "No, but..."

Comment: @haim770 That's correct, but it is implicitly 'yes' Am i right.? :)

Comment: Just wondering whether the OP already knew about this solution and asked specifically for the `setInterval` signature definition.

Answer (score 7):

If you need more than 2 functions executed in a sequence and you're doing this often, having to pass an anonymous function and then call each function individually is not ideal. You can abstract this:

```
// For functions with side effects
function sequence() {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(f,g) {
    return function() {
      f.apply(this, arguments);
      g.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  });
}

function hi(){ console.log('hi') }
function say(){ console.log('how are you?') }
function bye(){ console.log('bye') }

setTimeout(sequence(hi, say, bye), 1000);
//^ ...
//  hi
//  how are you?
//  bye
```

Now that's DRY.

Comment: DRY? `f.apply(this, arguments); g.apply(this, arguments);` Maybe that could be improved? :P

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yeah... you mean `g(f.apply(this, arguments))` or `f();g()`?

Comment: Frankly, I'm still trying to wrap my head around what that code does. I just noticed two lines that only had a single character difference.

Comment: Well, it creates a function that calls the given functions in a sequence. It looks similar to composition in a way. You could in fact compose them and it will still yield the same result assuming your functions are only for side-effects (they return undefined). Then `.apply(this, arguments)` is to make sure the context is set correctly.

Comment: Ah, I see. `f();g()` seems to be the best option, then, as you still can return values... However, what would be the point of returning values in a async function?

Answer (score 3):

yes

```
setInterval(function () {

    function1();
    function2();
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 3):

call it using another function

```
setInterval(function(){
    function1();
    function2();
},8000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can create a function which takes an arbitrary amount of functions as parameters, then wraps them all in a single function and returns that function.

```
function a() { alert("aaa"); }
function b() { alert("bbb"); }

function combine() {
    var args = arguments;

    // Return a single function, which when invoked,
    // will invoke all the functions that were passed to combine.
    return function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            args[i]();
        }
    };
}

setTimeout(combine(a, b), 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    function1();
    function2();
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with following way...

```
setInterval(function(){
    function1();
    function2();
},8000)
```